# How to autogenerate and apply migrations with alembic when the database runs in a container?

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, alembic

I find the workflow for working with database migrations in a containerized environment confusing. I have a web API with an attached database. The API runs in one container and the database in another. The project file structure is as follows

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── app
|    ├── __init__.py
|    ├── database
|    |    ├── alembic/
|    |    ├── __init__.py
|    |    ├── db.py
|    |    └── models.py
|    ├── other
|    ├── source
|    └── files
├── other
└── files
```

In order for the API container to be able to access the database the sqlalchemy.url in the ini-file is set to:

`postgresql://{username}:{password}@db:5432/{database}`

However when I want to do a migration, for example add a table column, I will change the model in `app/database/models.py` change directory to `app/database` and run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Description"`. This is where the problem occurs, I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

If I change the hostname to localhost it works but then the docker-compose breaks since it has to reference the container name.

This workflow does not seem right. How do people work with databases in projects which uses containers?

The `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=database

  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "cd app/database && alembic upgrade head && cd ../.. && python app/main.py"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your database has published `ports:`, you can access it directly from the host.  The application running outside a container on the host and the same application running in a Compose setup are different environments, and it's appropriate to use environment variables to specify this.  Do not hard-code a database location in your application.

If you can use the [standard PostgreSQL environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html), then it's fairly easy to specify this.

```sh
# To run migrations:
cd app/database
PGUSER=username PGPASSWORD=password PGDATABASE=database \
  alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Description"
# (assumes default PGHOST=localhost)
```

```yaml
# To run the application:
version: '3.8'
services:
  db: { ... }
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      PGHOST: db
      PGUSER: username
      PGPASSWORD: password
      PGDATABASE: database
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding health checks to @paltaa answer.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.0
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=database
    networks:
      - app-network    
  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "cd app/database && alembic upgrade head && cd ../.. && python app/main.py"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the network attached to both containers so the DNS can resolve to DB. So, add the same network to both containers as follows:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=database
    networks:
      - app-network    
  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "cd app/database && alembic upgrade head && cd ../.. && python app/main.py"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
```

As a side note, you have the ports mapped to 5432 on your localhost. There is a special docker DNS that points to the localhost where the containers are running, so you can use `host.docker.internal` inside your app container, which will resolve to your localhost.

Comment: it's redundant to define a single network for services that all use the same single network.